# getURL returns an "embedded nul in string" error when using the Stack Overflow API

Tags: curl

I am trying to load questions from the Stack Overflow API and I get an error about an embedded nul in the string.

```
document = getURL("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=15&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=R&site=stackoverflow")
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: '\037<U+008B>\b'
```

I've tried other methods of retrieving the page, but they result in a string of incomprehensible numbers and letters, such as using the function `getURLContent()`

Comment: What you get from `getURL` is a compressed JSON (through `gzip`). You have to decompress the object in order to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a https problem. Try `httr`:

```
content(GET("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=15&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=R&site=stackoverflow"))

$items
$items[[1]]
$items[[1]]$tags
$items[[1]]$tags[[1]]
[1] "r"

$items[[1]]$tags[[2]]
[1] "osx"

$items[[1]]$tags[[3]]
[1] "ggplot2"

... cut off
```

Comment: This was it. Removed the s in https and now it works.